# Count of distinct rows with duplicate email IDs

Tags: sql

How do I get count of distinct rows with duplicate email IDs in SQL?

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL 
1    John   asd@asd.com 
2    Sam    asd@asd.com 
4    Bob    bob@asd.com 
5    Tom    asd@asd.com 
6    Rob    bob@asd.com
7    Tic    tic@asd.com
8    Dad    dad@asd.com
```

The query should return 2.
as asd@asd.com and bob@asd.com are duplicates

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(*)  
FROM Users
GROUP BY EMail 
HAVING ( COUNT(EMAIL) > 1 )
```

This query is returning some wierd results.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Count of rows:

```
select sum(cnt)
from (select count(*) as cnt
    from Users
    group by email
    having count(*) > 1) T
```

Count of emails:

```
select count(*)
from (select count(*) as cnt
    from Users
    group by email
    having count(*) > 1) T
```

Both at once:

```
select count(*) as COUNT_EMAIL sum(cnt) as COUNT_ROWS
from (select count(*) as cnt
    from Users
    group by email
    having count(*) > 1) T
```

Above should work on SQL Server and Oracle.